# Band stop filter RLC circuit frequency response

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, frequency, phasor

Assume we have an $ RLC $ circuit as described in the picture

[image]

This should be a Band-stop filter. But somethings bother me in my calculations. This is my calculations for the frequency response:

Using the impedance of the inductor and the capacitor, and using voltage divider, we conclude:

$$ V_{out}=\frac{\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{\left(j\omega L+\frac{1}{j\omega C}+R\right)}V_{in}=\frac{1}{\left(1-\omega^{2}LC\right)+R}V_{in} $$

Where $$ V_{out},V_{in} $$
represents phasors.

So now the amplitude given by:
$$ |\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\omega^{2}LC\right)^{2}+\left(\omega RC\right)^{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-4\pi^{2}LCf^{2}\right)^{2}+\left(2\pi RCf\right)^{2}}}$$

And now if I'll try to plot the graph of the amplitude of the frequency response for, say $$ \begin{cases}
R=300\varOmega\\
L=84mH\\
C=8.3nF
\end{cases} $$

This is what I get by desmos:

[image]

Which does not seem like a Band Stop Filter, as we can see here for example: (photo that I found online)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance. This is very appreciated.

Comment: This is not a notch filter - bandstop.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Is this a band pass filiter?

Comment: @FreeZe yes that is true, it is a band-pass.

Comment: @Jan I see. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Jan No. It could be lowpass, but not bandstop or bandpass.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič true!

Comment: This is a lowpass, plain and simple. The transfer function should make it clear that it's of the form `1/(s^2+s+1)`.

Comment: Yes - the classical form of a 2nd-order passive RLC-lowpass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a low pass filter. At DC the inductor acts like a short circuit and the capacitor acts like an open circuit. Therefore it lets DC pass. This rules it out as being a band-stop filter.

At high frequencies the inductor blocks input signals producing much output signal and the capacitor shunts high frequencies hence, it is a low pass filter: -

[image]

[Link to LPF calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html).

It can produce a resonance around the natural frequency of the circuit but, it's still a low pass filter.